# Uploading data from local computer to Hive DB using Hue

Tags: hive, hue, hiveql

Relative Newbie to using Hive and Hue.

Is there a way to upload a file saved to my laptop to a database table in Hive, using Hue?  I've been looking through books and scouring the Web, but haven't found any answer.

Harry

Answer (score 0):

This is easy in the Hive/Beeswax app: click on the Beeswax icon, then 'Tables' tab and then either create a new table from the file (which has an option for uploading it) or select an existing table with a compatible schema and click on 'Import Data'.